# Spectrum in terms of two spectra in bounded Hilbert spaces.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, direct-sum, spectra

If we have $H_1,H_2$ as hilbert spaces, then
$$H_1\oplus H_2:=\{(h,k):h\in H_1, k\in H_2\}$$
then it is also a Hilbert space with the following,
$$(h_1,k_1)+(h_2,k_2):=(h_1+h_2,k_1+k_2)$$ and $$\langle (h_1,k_1),(h_2,k_2) \rangle:=\langle h_1,k_1\rangle+\langle h_2,k_2\rangle$$
and so on... Now let $T_1\in H_1$ and $T_2\in H_2$ then we have $T_1\oplus T_2\in B(H_1\oplus H_2)$ defined by the following,
$$(T_1\oplus T_2)(h,k):=(T_1h,T_2k)$$
One can think $T_1\oplus T_2$ as a diagonal matrix acting on column vectors, i.e.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
T_1 & 0 \\
0 & T_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
h \\k
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
T_1h \\ T_2k
\end{pmatrix}$$
So I believe we still can compute the spectrum of $\sigma (T_1\oplus T_2)$ in terms of $\sigma(T_1)$ and $\sigma(T_2)$ but still I'm stuck. I've discussed with few others that we can use linear algebra methods but what kind of matrix should I use? Should we use the norm of $T_1\oplus T_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
\sigma(T_1\oplus T_2)=\sigma(T_1)\cup\sigma(T_2).
$$
All you need to show is that $T_1\oplus T_2$ is invertible if and only if $T_1$ and $T_2$ and both invertible.

If you write
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ C&D\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T_1&0\\0&T_2\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix} ,\qquad 
\begin{bmatrix} T_1&0\\0&T_2\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ C&D\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix} 
$$
you get
$$
AT_1=T_1A=I,\qquad BT_2=T_1B=0,\qquad CT_1=T_2B=0,\qquad DT_2=T_2D=I. 
$$
The first and last equations give you $A=T_1^{-1}$, $D=T_2^{-1}$, and then $B=C=0$. So, when $T_1\oplus T_2$ is invertible then $T_1,T_2$ are invertible and $(T_1\oplus T_2)^{-1}=T_1^{-1}\oplus T_2^{-1}$.

Conversely, if $T_1,T_2$ are both invertible, then $T_1\oplus T_2$ is invertible and $(T_1\oplus T_2)^{-1}=T_1^{-1}\oplus T_2^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! So when one needs to compute $\sigma (T_1\oplus T_2)$ then one have to show invertible? I though that one should use the spectrum definition. I mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)
Under the section “Spectrum of a bounded operator”. And further compute the eigenvalues. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: From your link: "a complex number $λ$ is said to be in the spectrum of a bounded linear operator $T$ if ${\displaystyle T-\lambda I}$ is not **invertible**".

Comment: I am just unsure if I should find $\lambda$ or not. So the idea when computing $\sigma (T_1 \oplus T_2)$ is just to show that it is invertible. Another question. What value are my $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: **Definition:** Let $A\in \mathscr{A}$, where $\mathscr{A}$ is a unital Banach algebra. The spectrum of $A$ denoted $\sigma(A)$ is $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:A-\lambda I \text{ is not invertible in } \mathscr{A}\}$.

Comment: And a side note: I believe we are working with finite dimensional Hilbert spaces and therefore I gave the definition. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: You never said that your spaces were finite-dimensional, so I don't know.

Comment: If it is finite then how would one be able to compute the spectrum? I understand the definition for spectrum but to apply it on this one is difficult for me.

Comment: In finite dimension, the spectrum consists entirely of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes. And the eigenvalues can be found by the determinant i.e. $\det(\lambda I-T_1)=0$ for $\sigma(T_1)$ which is a easy task if I know what $T_1$ is. I don’t know... I can’t just pick a random matrix and use that. The same for $T_2$. Do you know what matrices I need? Then I will try to find the spectrums.

Comment: Sorry, you are not making any sense. In your question you wrote "let $T_1\in H_1$ and $T_2\in H_2$". And now you are asking me to tell **you** what $T_1$ and $T_2$ are? Explicitly?

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you with the question. I am new to this. I just think that we indeed could compute the spectrums $\sigma(T_1)$ and $\sigma(T_2)$ i.e. find possible eigenvalues (numbers) for these and then take the union. Maybe this is impossible in this case. I’m glad that you help me. Notice (which you might know) these $T_1$ and $T_2$ are bounded operators

Comment: But what you are asking is exactly the same as if in a problem it would say "let $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and then you are asking me what $x$ and $y$ are. In infinite dimension, if you choose any two compact subsets $K_1,K_2\subset\mathbb C$, it is possible to find $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $\sigma(T_1)=K_1$, $\sigma(T_2)=K_2$.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean and therefore my comment does not make sense. Thanks. And how would you do that if you take such a compact subsets?

Comment: In finite dimension, if you want to prescribe the $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ of a matrix, you take $T$ to be the diagonal matrix with the desired eigenvalues in the diagonal. In infinite dimension, you do basically the same. Given $K\subset\mathbb C$ compact, you choose a countable dense subset $\{q_n\}$ and put the $q_n$ on the diagonal.

Comment: But again, thanks for helping me and your time, Martin. I will stop for now. I cannot see me through this problem and maybe later I will learn how it could be done. I will now continue with functional analysis.